# How to get only a piece of an URL? (php)

Tags: php, url

I have this url:

```
example.com/?do=search&q=testing+this+out
```

I need to store the part after &q= in a variable.

What PHP function would be the best for doing that, explode, slice?

P.S. I use `$request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to get the URI.

Comment: you want `parse_url()`  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the value of q, you can simply write:

```
$value = $_GET['q'];
```

Comment: I think OP has a string containing the url and wants to decompose that, not an actual url for the currently executing script.

Answer (score 4):

There's `parse_url()` to slice 'n dice a url into its components, then `parse_str()` will take a query string and decompose it into a regular key-value array.

```
$url = 'your url here';
$parts = parse_url($url);
$query = parse_str($parts['query']);
echo $query['q'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why $_GET is not sufficient. But incase it isn't, here:

```
$ php -r '$url = "http://example.com/?do=search&q=testing+this+out"; $parts = parse_url($url); $vars = explode("&", $parts["query"]); print_r($vars);'
Array
(
    [0] => do=search
    [1] => q=testing+this+out
)
```

Answer (score 0):

mabye more quick and more simple...

```
$requested_query_vars = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
```

or parse_url() php function

```
$requested_query_vars = parse_url($request_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```